# CkEditor - How to add link attribute in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I`m using CKEditor on my website.

I need adding select input for follow attribute in link plugin

i.e.
< a href="link_target" rel="nofollow">Hyper link< /a>

[Customize from left to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpxj6.png)

I try many time. but not implemented yet.

How to customize the select options?

It is my customize code of link.js

/ckeditor/plugins/link/dialogs/link.js

```
            {
                id: "followOptions",
                type: "select",
                label: b.followOptions,
                "default": "doFollow",
                items: [
                    [b.doFollow, "doFollow"],
                    [b.noFollow, "noFollow"]
                ], setup: function (a) {
                    this.setValue(a.followOptions || "")

                }, commit: function (a) {
                    a.followOptions = this.getValue()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please show us all your relevant code

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I added my code to my question. Please check the code